# Informatica Java Transformation for replacing spaces in a string

Tags: java, arrays, string, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I'm trying to implement a Java transformation in Informatica which has to do a simple task of replacing all the Spaces in an array of strings.

I've tried the following:

```
OriginalArray[i] = OriginalArray[i].replace("\\s","");

OriginalArray[i] = OriginalArray[i].replaceAll("\\s","");
```

but none of them replace the spaces. Kindly assist me here.

Comment: `replace` doesn't use regex syntax so `replace("\\s","")` will simply try to remove string representing `\s` literal. But `replaceAll` uses regex, so this solution should work which suggests that your problem is not in this code. Are you sure that your spaces are whitespaces (and not for instance non-breaking-space)?

Comment: Since you are new on Stack Overflow you may not know that to update your question with more informations use need to use [edit] option.

Comment: Also, please share the reason, why you want to use a java transformation for this task instead of simple expressions in your mapping. Java transformation should only be used in very special cases in my opinion.

Comment: Reason is that, I have about 128 columns of data incoming where I need to apply this. Also, Once I replace the spaces, I would need to loop through them for implementing a logic.